# Combining jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked through much of the material via search.

first animation shows object that is off screen.

second animation scrolls to object using url.com/#bottom

```
$( "#contactbtn" ).click(function() {
    $( "#contactform" ).show( "fast", function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
});



$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
 });
```

Each animation works great independently, but when combined they occur instantly and conflict causing
a none fluid transition to the element. Would like to know way of combining, perhaps by delay or queuing.

Comment: How did you try to combine the animations?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
var onClickFun = function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', animateFun());
}

function animateFun()(event) {
var target = $(this.href);
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}

$( "#contactbtn" ).click(function() {
$( "#contactform" ).show( "fast", onClickFun());
```

});

Call second animation only after first is complete and give time lag according to your requirement.

Comment: On line 2 of your code, your callback is actually calling `animateFun` immediately because you provided the `()`. Please just use `.on('click', animateFun)`. The same is true of your last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close - in fact, your comment `// Animation complete` is exactly where the next animation goes!

Many jQuery animations, including `show()` and `animate()`, accept a callback function as their last parameter. This lets you do something only once the animation is complete. For your example, if you wanted to show the contact form and then add the listener for anchor tags:

```
$( "#contactbtn" ).click(function() {
    $( "#contactform" ).show( "fast", function() {
        //* Right here we are in the callback to the .show() method. 
        //* This code below is only run once the element has been shown.
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this.href);
            if ( target.length ) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
       });
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can make scrollToAnchor its own function. This way you can keep your code tidy and just pass it as a callback. Callback functions receive arguments in the same order that they are passed. In this case, the event object will be passed to scrollToAnchor.

You can see how this code is both more readable and will be easier to maintain.

```
function scrollToAnchor(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this.href);
    if ( target.length ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
}

$( "#contactbtn" ).click(function() {
    $( "#contactform" ).show( "fast", function() {
        //* Right here we are in the callback to the .show() method. 
        //* This code below is only run once the element has been shown.
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', scrollToAnchor);
    });
});
```